# Let $\vec{a}=(3,-2,1),\vec{b}=(1,1,-4)$. Find the angle $\alpha$ between planes $P_1,P_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\vec{a}=(3,-2,1),\vec{b}=(1,1,-4)$. Find the angle $\alpha$ between planes $P_1,P_2$ where $\vec{a},\vec{b} \in P_1$ and $\vec{a},\vec{b}+\vec{a }\times \vec{b} \in P_2$.

My idea:
Find the normal vectors for $P_1,P_2$ and then calculate the angle between them.

$\vec{n_1}=\vec{a} \times \vec{b} = (7,13,5)$

$\vec{n_2}=\vec{a} \times (\vec{b}+\vec{a} \times \vec{b})=(-16,5,58)$

$|\vec{n_1}|=9\sqrt{3}$

$|\vec{n_2}|=9\sqrt{42}$

$(\vec{n_1},\vec{n_2})=243$

$\alpha = arccos(\frac{3}{\sqrt{126}})$

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful to state what your thoughts and attempts on the problem are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: @projectilemotion Thank you for the kind proposal. I've edited my question

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation. It may also help if you stated exactly where this problem comes from.

Comment: @projectilemotion I've added my approach. Hope someone could review it